# JavaFX: CSS selector for text elements in TextFlow

Tags: java, css, javafx

What is the css selector for Text elements in a TextFlow?
I'm doing the following and its not working unless I apply the style directly to the text node

```
<TextFlow styleClass="paragraph">
     <Text text="some text"></Text>
</TextFlow>

.paragraph .text {
     -fx-font-size: 14.0px;
     -fx-text-fill: -fx-font-colour-black;
     -fx-fill: -fx-font-colour-black;
}
```

Comment: @trashgod I've updated my question. Its not duplicate. My meaning is how do I select with css selectors. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Text` does not have a [default style-class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#text), therefore the selector `.text` does not work.

> Style class: empty by default

You can use a [type selector](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#introscenegraph) (as proposed by James_D in his comment):

```
.paragraph Text { ... }.
```

or you can add that style-class to your `Text` objects, when you create them:

```
Text text = new Text("my Text");
text.getStyleClass().add("text");
```

or you can even update the selector to select everything in your `TextFlow`:

```
.paragraph > * {
          -fx-font-size: 14.0px;
          -fx-text-fill: red;
          -fx-fill: red;
 }
```

Comment: Or use a [Type selector](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#introscenegraph): `.paragraph Text { ... }`.

Comment: Yes, this one maybe the best approach, thanks. Updated the answer.